# Identify and cancel an alarm send to an AlarmManager

Tags: android, schedule, alarm, alarmmanager, android-alarms

If I use the AlarmManager to schedule an alarm (a PendintIntent which should be send), how can I identify that alarm later to cancel it? Can I cancel all alarms scheduled by my app?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You probably want to have a closer look at the [`AlarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent operation)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) function.

Comment: was just writing that as well :). This is the right answer. For operation you need to use the same one or what needs to match with the first one is: data, type, class, and categories.

Comment: Thanks, so I have to save a reference to the pending intent, but what if my app is finished? How to cancel the alarms on the next start?

Comment: If I could cancel all alarms set by my app that would solve that problem easily..

Comment: @cody: you'd have to re-create the `PendingIntent` if you want to cancel the alarms on the next start. I don't think there is an easy way to cancel all alarms set by your app. The documentation for the `cancel` function says: *any alarm, of any type, whose Intent matches this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)), will be canceled.* You should take a look at the documentation for `filterEquals(Intent)`, as this will explain to you the specifics of how this works.