# How to start Service using Alarm Manager in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

In my application, I am trying to start a service using Alarm manager. When I am clicking a button service should start in a particular time which I am giving. 
 My code for Alarm Manager is given below:

```
public void onClick(View view) 
{
    if(view == m_btnActivate)
    {
        Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cur_cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 50);
        Log.d("Testing", "Calender Set time:"+cur_cal.getTime());
        Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardScreen.this, ServiceClass.class);
        Log.d("Testing", "Intent created");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardScreen.this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
        Log.d("Testing", "alarm manager set");
        Toast.makeText(this, "ServiceClass.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And bellow is my Service Class:

```
    public class ServiceClass extends Service{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("Testing", "Service got created");
        Toast.makeText(this, "ServiceClass.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "ServiceClass.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("Testing", "Service got started");
    }

}
```

If the service will start it should print the log messages in the service class. But it is not showing. Can any one help?

Comment: I mentioned the name, but not Android:enabled = "true"

Comment: Use alarmManager.cancel(pintent); to cancel the alarm manager.

Comment: `Android:enabled` by default is `true`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This is what I have used, for starting service after 30 seconds from current time,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardScreen.this, ServiceClass.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardScreen.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
```

Try it, and let me know what happen...

EDIT:

In your manifest.xml file

```
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".ServiceClass" />
```

Comment: Yes it is working..thanks..but now how can i stop the service in a particular time??

Comment: can you help me for the above question?? How can i stop the alarm manager in a particular time..

Comment: Use  alarmManager.cancel(pintent); to stop the alarm manager.

Comment: I tried with the filterEquals() method..can you please checke?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212824/identify-and-cancel-an-alarm-send-to-an-alarmmanager

Comment: So again i have to create another intent or not?

Comment: Intent intent2 = new Intent(DashboardScreen.this, com.innominds.util.ServiceClass.class);
   PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardScreen.this, req, intent2, 0);
   AlarmManager alarm_stop = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_stop.getTimeInMillis(), pi2);
   if(intent2.filterEquals(intent))
   {
    alarm_stop.cancel(pi);
   }

Comment: No, try to use same intent for cancelling the alarm your pintent.

Comment: No if i use the same intent then i can use that filterEquals() method?

Comment: Look at [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmController.html), [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html) and [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm) also [Cancel Alarm using alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent) ](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/05/cancel-alarm-using-alarmmanagercancelpe.html) then you can understand what I want to say..

Comment: i wrote the below code:  Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardScreen.this, com.innominds.util.ServiceClass.class);
   Log.d("Testing", "Intent created");
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardScreen.this, req, intent, 0);
   AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(),30*1000, pi);
   Log.d("Testing", "Intent created");
   AlarmManager alarm_stop = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarm_stop.cancel(pi);

Comment: do i still need a BroadcastReceiver when using this? or i only need two files? the activity and the service?

Comment: Does this code work for Android Oreo version and above? `If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes restrictions on using or creating background services unless the app itself is in the foreground`

Comment: Isn't the minimum time between alarms 60 seconds?

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old question, but just to help the people from google, here is how you can keep your service alive.

```
    Intent ishintent = new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, ishintent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(pintent);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),5000, pintent);
```

The service is killed and restarted every 5 seconds.

Comment: Value will be forced up to 60000ms for android 5, don't rely... you have to wait 1mins then. thanks anyway