# android process died with (adj *), what is adj?

Tags: android

On my Galaxy S III, using logcat I can see very frequently that process died.

What does (adj 5), (adj 8), (adj 9) and (adj 10) mean?

following are device logcat :-

```
I/ActivityManager( 2258): Process com.google.android.partnersetup (pid 32242) (adj 10) has died.

I/ActivityManager( 2258): Process com.metago.astro (pid 32446) (adj 10) has died.

D/dalvikvm(32602): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
I/ActivityManager( 2258): Process com.google.android.gms (pid 32272) (adj 10) has died.

I/ActivityManager( 2258): Process com.whatsapp (pid 12041) (adj 8) has died.

D/KeyguardViewMediator( 2258): setHidden false
D/WindowManager( 2258): mInputFocus is not null.
I/ActivityManager( 2258): Process com.sec.spp.push (pid 19839) (adj 8) has died.

I/ActivityManager( 2258): Process com.test.happ.jiffy (pid 556) (adj 5) has died.
```

Comment: You can find more information in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14748123/383414 Looks like this is normal behavior for some case

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/17955940/1145140 I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 5):

When memory low, android system will kill some background process, every process has an adj value which represents its importance. The lower the adj value, the higher the importance of the process. High adj processes will be killed first.

the value define in ProcessList.java

```
class ProcessList {
    // The minimum time we allow between crashes, for us to consider this
    // application to be bad and stop and its services and reject broadcasts.
    static final int MIN_CRASH_INTERVAL = 60*1000;

    // OOM adjustments for processes in various states:

    // This is a process only hosting activities that are not visible,
    // so it can be killed without any disruption.
    static final int HIDDEN_APP_MAX_ADJ = 15;
    static int HIDDEN_APP_MIN_ADJ = 9;

    // The B list of SERVICE_ADJ -- these are the old and decrepit
    // services that aren't as shiny and interesting as the ones in the A list.
    static final int SERVICE_B_ADJ = 8;

    // This is the process of the previous application that the user was in.
    // This process is kept above other things, because it is very common to
    // switch back to the previous app.  This is important both for recent
    // task switch (toggling between the two top recent apps) as well as normal
    // UI flow such as clicking on a URI in the e-mail app to view in the browser,
    // and then pressing back to return to e-mail.
    static final int PREVIOUS_APP_ADJ = 7;

    // This is a process holding the home application -- we want to try
    // avoiding killing it, even if it would normally be in the background,
    // because the user interacts with it so much.
    static final int HOME_APP_ADJ = 6;
```

More about android memory managerment can refer http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html