# receiver and service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

With the courtesy of an stackoverlow user we written this code. Should be starts a toast at specify hour but doesn't run.

Can someone help me to discover where's the problem?
thanks!

```
public class UnUsedService extends Service {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//startService(new Intent(this, UnUsedService.class));
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
//Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

//  super.onStart();
super.onStart(intent, startId);

Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//Toast.makeText(UnUsedService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)     getApplicationContext().getSystemService  (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(),     AlarmReceiver.class),      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

}};
```

The receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
 }
```

Manifest:

```
<service android:name="UnUsedService">
        <intent-filter>
        <action
        android:name="org.gortcloud.startatboot.UnUsedService" />
        </intent-filter>
        </service>

<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote"/>
```

Comment: you realize that the Alarm you are setting up will start Today at 22:30, and rerun only once per day...right? who starts the service?

Comment: Yep. In the mainActivity I've: startService(new Intent(this, UnUsedService.class)); (I start service from mainActivity only for purpose test). The whole code use "autostart after boot of android".

Comment: so...what's the problem? is the `am.setRepeating(...)` getting run? you're just not getting to `AlarmReceiver`??

Comment: Problem: I see toast (Service Started) but I don't see the toast "Alarm worked." (at specify hour).

Comment: you might want to shorten the time (for testing purposes) when the alarm starts and repeats...otherwise you'll have to wait a LOOOOONG time to see results

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on something similar. can you replace `receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"` with `receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote"` that worked for me.

Comment: i have `PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`

Comment: hmmmm. this setup worked for me (i probably "borrowed" the same code you did...although i changed it to kickoff via a button on the main activity.) can you look thru the logcat for your application name...you might find something interesting there.

Comment: This afternoon I created this exact code to new project: only this code (with a mainActivity to starts service). Does not run... :-/

Comment: also, pls shorten the amount of time when the alarm kicks off and repeats. you have `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` i have `calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 1000 // one second`. for the repeating part you have `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` i am using (testing) `(10 * 1000) // 10 seconds`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21096/discussion-between-pol-hallen-and-david-m)

Answer (score 0):

ok...i got this to work. i followed [How to start Service using Alarm Manager in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321443/how-to-start-service-using-alarm-manager-in-android). basically i *was* using a `pendingIntent.setBroadcast(..)` which requires a BroadcastReceiver, now i'm using `pendingIntent.setService(...)`

i have a class that extends IntentService (with a noarg constructor). I'm successfully getting the alarm to trigger starting this service. i have an `onStart()` and `onStartCommand()` and `onHandleIntent()` that each get run (i assume you would only implement one of them)

hope this helps you.