# Why an Alarm Broadcast receiver not receiving broadcast?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I am trying to start a service at specific intervals with help of a `BroadcastReceiver`. I have defined the receiver as **an inner class in service itself** as follows:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("RTESPLDebug", "Recieved Broadcast!"); //Never appears in LogCat
        //Intent i = new Intent(context, LocationUpdateService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
};
```

I register the alarm receiver in service's `onCreate()`:

```
context = super.getApplicationContext();

AlarmReceiver ar = new AlarmReceiver();
IntentFilter intfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
intfilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
registerReceiver(ar, intfilter);
```

I first start the service from my first activity and then register a single alarm there:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, LocationUpdateService.class);
context.startService(i);

// Schedule first alarm
int nextUpdateInterval = 30*1000; // Let first alarm be after 30 sec
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationUpdateService.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis()+nextUpdateInterval, pintent);
```

In the service I register for a single location update, and when I receive update (I do receive), I process it (I have debugged this, processing indeed completes without errors), and then I register next alarm in similar way as above:

```
int nextUpdateInterval = getNextUpdateInterval(); // Returns 30000
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationUpdateService.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis()+nextUpdateInterval, pintent);
```

Lots of code and a long questions.

Comment: change this line PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, RQS_1, intent, 0); and see what happens.

Comment: thanks, let me try this

Comment: @Vinoth - well RQS_1 is not defined, and the documentation says this field is currently not used

Comment: go through this link may be helpful to you  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321443/how-to-start-service-using-alarm-manager-in-android

Comment: The link doesn't help. I had seen it already.

Comment: change this to Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class); and try