# How to start the intent service using alarm manager

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start my intent service with alarm manager and my intent service is being started by service .. but i am unable to do that please help me to do so
this is my code
service code

```
public void onCreate() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);

        startService(intent);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                10 * 1000, pintent);
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10 * 1000, pintent);

    }


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in service onSatrt commandf ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();

        intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);

        startService(intent);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                10 * 1000, pintent);
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10 * 1000, pintent);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start Service using Alarm Manager in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321443/how-to-start-service-using-alarm-manager-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

try this

You need to Use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Change your code from   `PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);` to

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
                        0,  serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply .. but do i need to define the other intent for pending intent ....... and in which life cycle phase(in which function) should i define so it will run without interrupt

Comment: you can use the exiting intent as you used in your question

Comment: its not working ... please suggest me some other way !!

Comment: where you called this?? do try the link under your question ?

Comment: do you check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321443/how-to-start-service-using-alarm-manager-in-android