# How to get PendingIntent id for canceling pendingintent

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have been working with an Alarm Manager. Once I set a `PendingIntent` for triggering the alarm, I want to cancel it.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212824/identify-and-cancel-an-alarm-send-to-an-alarmmanager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These following code will remove/cancel the pending intent and alarm.

The main thing that you will need is:

- Create pending intent with the same id and appropriate intent FLAG.
- Cancel that pending intent.
- Cancel the alarm using alarm manager.

Code:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(PresentActivity.this, AlarmActivity.class);          
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(PresentActivity.this,pending_intent_unique_id, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    pendingIntent.cancel();
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the running pendingintents? I need to update the timer clock based on the time left for the alarm, after the app was closed and reopened.